# Representing Null values differently when serializing objects to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am serializing objects to XML like so using the following code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass thisClass = new MyClass() { One = "Foo", Two = string.Empty, Three = "Bar" };
            Serialize<MyClass>(thisClass, @"C:\Users\JMK\Desktop\x.xml");
        }

        static void Serialize<T>(T x, string fileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer v = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            TextWriter f = new StreamWriter(fileName);
            v.Serialize(f, x);
            f.Close();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string One { get; set; }
        public string Two { get; set; }
        public string Three { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This results in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <One>Foo</One>
  <Two />
  <Three>Bar</Three>
</MyClass>
```

This is all well and good, apart from one thing. If one of my values is null, I can't omit this from the XML, it needs to be there, and I can't represent it as `<Two />`, instead I need to represent this as `<Two></Two>`.

Is this possible using my current method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string Two { get; set; }
```

you can represent it as `<Two xsi:nil="true" />`

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the XML at all, I have posted the exact code I am using above, I have just added `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` above my second automatic property and I still get the same output.

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood the problem. If you use the code above nothing will change in xml. You'll get `xsi:nil` if `Two = null`.

Comment: Ah of course, doh! I'm not sure if the people we are sending the file to will be happy with this either but I will give it a shot. Thanks