# Force XML to have Closing tags?

Tags: wpf, xml, silverlight

I have a code that creates an XDocument and in that, I add XElements using the System.Xml.Linq class. Only the problem is, if the xml nodes doesn't have values, it returns an already closed tag. i.e.

```
 <Title />
```

But I was kinda achieving to create an XML that shows both opening tags and close tags. i.e.

```
<Title></Title>
```

even though it doesn't have value. Is there  some way I can work it to make it look like this?

P.S.: I am saving this code in the database, under a table column that accepts the data type xml, so adding a string.Empty gets closed on the Database, so FML. Any ideas?

Comment: The two ways of writing that element are equivalent as far as XML is concerned. Any tool handling XML should not stumble over one or the other.

Comment: unfortunately, client wants to see opening and closing tags, so I got a big problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning `InnerText` of the XmlNode with `""`. This action will apparently makes it expand into `<> </>` form.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the value of the Tag with `string.Empty`.

Comment: I tried using `XDocument` and adding an `XElement` "key" with value `string.Empty` but this transformed into `</key>` instead of `<key></key>` so that doesn't work

Comment: A correction for the above as I was writing my `XML` to `SQL`, it was `SQL server` itself that transformed `<key></key>` into `<key/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` attribute to represent null values with `xsi:nil="true"`, that was a close as I could get.

The only alternative I could find is to create your XML file, and then use StreamReader and StreamWriter to load your completed XML document into a string with StreamReader, use the `Replace()` method to find and replace each potentially null tag with opening and closing tags and then use StreamWriter to overwrite your XML file with your new string.

[Representing Null values differently when serializing objects to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362313/representing-null-values-differently-when-serializing-objects-to-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Use XDocument.WriteTo method to write the XDocument to an XmlWriter. Implement a custom XmlWriter which wraps a standard XmlWriter obtained via XmlWriter.Create, and pass your custom XmlWriter to the WriteTo method.

The custom XmlWriter should simply pass all calls through unmodified to the wrapped XmlWriter except for the WriteEndElement method, which should be:

```
    public override void WriteEndElement()
    {
        wrapped.WriteFullEndElement();
    }
```